# Does jpeg's embedded thumbnail equal to EXIF thumbnail?

Tags: jpeg, thumbnails, exif

Does jpeg's embedded thumbnail equal to EXIF thumbnail?
How can I retrieve jpeg's embedded thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo exif_thumbnail('image.jpg');
```